# SL, Take profit and EMA

Tags: loss-function

Can some please help me here. I am facing issues in 3 things here -

1. SL ( I want it to be 40 points below my entry price,
   2.Take profit (I want it to be 60 points above my entry price
2. EMA ( I want to use 20 ema as it is refereed to in my entry conditions)

I am expecting pinescript code for each one of the three things